# Injecting data to a WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, dependency-injection, service

I have WCF services structured like suggested by [Miguel Castro](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122). This means that I have set everything up manually, and have a console application hosting my services using [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) objects.

I want to keep my service classes thin, and they are currently just passing on calls to behavior classes. My problem now is unit testing the service classes. I want to inject something to the classes as a constructor parameter such that I can mock this away and write proper isolated unit tests. The ServiceHost class doesn't seem to accept arguments, so my question is how I can inject data to the service classes - or can't I?

Comment: are you using an IoC-container? and if yes which one?

Comment: I'm not using an IoC-container on the server side yet. Planning to introduce one now. Am using Unity on the client side (as it came with Prism), but consider using StructureMap on the server. Open for anyone really.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

WCF supports **Constructor Injection**, but you have to jump through a few hoops to get there. The key lies in writing a custom ServiceHostFactory. While that, too, must have a default constructor, you can use it to wire up all the correct behaviors.

As an example, I recently wrote one that uses Castle Windsor to wire up dependencies for the service implementation. The implementation of CreateServiceHost simply does this:

```
return new WindsorServiceHost(this.container, serviceType, baseAddresses);
```

where `this.container` is a configured IWindsorContainer.

WindsorServiceHost looks like this:

```
public class WindsorServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public WindsorServiceHost(IWindsorContainer container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        foreach (var cd in this.ImplementedContracts.Values)
        {
            cd.Behaviors.Add(new WindsorInstanceProvider(container));
        }
    }
}
```

and WindsorInstanceProvider looks like this:

```
public class WindsorInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorInstanceProvider(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }

        this.container = container;
    }

    #region IInstanceProvider Members

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return this.GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var serviceType = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType;
        return this.container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        this.container.Release(instance);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IContractBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This may look like a lot, but notice that it's reusable, general-purpose code that has a rather low cyclomatic complexity.

You can follow the same coding idiom to implement Dependency Injection with another DI Container or by using Poor Man's DI.

Here's an [older writeup](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/06/27/modifying-behavior-of-wcf-free-service-implementations.aspx) of this idiom that uses Poor Man's DI.

Comment: The Windsor WCF Facility wasn't in any sort of stable state when I originally wrote this answer. In any case, the answer explains how to support Constructor Injection in WCF with any DI Container: just replace IWindsorContainer with your container of choice.

Answer (score 5):

If you were using Castle Windsor, it has a great WCF integration facility that lets you do this, and a lot more very easily.

Answer (score 1):

did you configure your service as a Singleton? i found out that IInstanceProvider implementations may be problematic when using a DI container to create the service instances.

Answer (score 0):

The article [Hosting a Mock as a WCF service](http://bronumski.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/hosting-mock-as-wcf-service.html)
 contains a static method that will generate a WCF service host based on the object that is passed into the method with a single endpoint.

The method  was also posted in the  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306934/52277) for [Recommended patterns for unit testing web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587393/recommended-patterns-for-unit-testing-web-services).

Example of usage calls NSubstitute, but other mocking freameworks can be used.