# Proper way of consuming WCF Services in WPF Application using DI

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, dependency-injection

The problem is that contrary to controllers in MVC, MVVM models in WPF are instantiated and are *there* for good. Practically what that means for me is that if I have a private property in my viemodel my proxy will be open for a long time eg.:

```
//Some example after googling for "consuming wcf services in wpf app~"
private FootballerServices.FootballerServiceClient footballersService = null;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    footballersService = new FootballerServices.FootballerServiceClient();
    try
    {
        FootballerBox.ItemsSource = footballersService.GetFootballers();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

How do I solve that issue properly?

**First solution:**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyServicesClient proxy = new MyServicesClient();

    try
    {
        MyServicesData data = proxy.GetDataFromMyService();

        proxy.Close();
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fault Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then I could make a new class like ServiceWrapper where I would encapsulate all the method calls:
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var t = serviceWrapper.GetDataFromMyService();
        (...)
    }

and in Service Wrapper:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyServicesClient proxy = new MyServicesClient();

    try
    {
        MyServicesData data = proxy.GetDataFromMyService();

        proxy.Close();
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        (...)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        (...)
    }

    return data;
}
```

Now the last thing would be to add DI to that solution

**Second Solution**

Another way that I found is to use Abstract Factory pattern with DI like it was answered here:

[Dependency Injection wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010820/dependency-injection-wcf)

I do not fully understand this solution, however. 
My understanding was that it happens like this:
DI resolves an instance of my ServiceClient and after execution goes out scope of the method that used the resolved instance, the DI container disposes of that instance - that there is no need for Abstract factory pattern.
Apparently, my understanding was wrong.

**Question: What is the proper practice in such case?**

Comment: Are  you saying the issue with your first attempt is that you can't read from the queryable list returned  by `GetFootballers()` after disposing/closing the service client? If so, why not just use `.ToArray()`? If you're going to fill a listbox with them they have to all be read into memory anyway, so presumably there aren't 1000s and 1000s of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely wouldn't want to inject a WCF client because you only need it for a very short time. What you can inject is a factory that will return the service when needed.

The factory interface may look like this:

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory
{
    IMyService Create();
    void Release(IMyService created);
}
```

Assume that you're injecting this through your constructor and adding a private readonly field to your class, like this:

```
private readonly IMyServiceFactory _myServiceFactory;
```

Then when you need the service, you do this:

```
var myService = _myServiceFactory.Create();
try
{
   // do something with the service
}
finally
{
   _myService.Release(myService);
}
```

A big benefit is that your class depends entirely on abstractions. It doesn't "know" that the service is implemented by a WCF client or that the factory is calling a DI container. You can test it using a mock of `IMyService`. That's impossible if your class is directly creating its own WCF client.

You didn't mention which container you're using, but many of them will create WCF clients for you to implement interfaces.

- [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html)
- [Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/wcf-facility.md) - their documentation is lacking at this point. In the off chance that you're using Windsor I can provide more detail.

Another nice detail about Windsor is that it will also [create the abstract factory for you](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md).

---

Here's a few more pieces to make up a sample implementation using Windsor. This supposes that you have a WCF service that implements `IMyService`.

Here's the service interface, the factory interface, and the class that consumes it:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetSomeData();
}

public interface IMyServiceFactory
{
    IMyService Create();
    void Release(IMyService created);
}

public class ClassThatConsumesService
{
    private readonly IMyServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public ClassThatConsumesService(IMyServiceFactory myServiceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = myServiceFactory;
    }

    public void MethodThatDoesSomething()
    {
        var service = _serviceFactory.Create();
        try
        {
            var data = service.GetSomeData();
            // do whatever
        }
        finally
        {
            _serviceFactory.Release(service);
        }
    }
}
```

Then here's an example of some implementation details using Windsor. But one important detail is that nothing above depends on Windsor. You could do this using a different DI container. You don't even need a DI container at all. All your class knows is that it's calling a factory to get an instance of a service.

```
public class ClassThatConsumesService
{
    private readonly IMyServiceFactory _serviceFactory;

    public ClassThatConsumesService(IMyServiceFactory myServiceFactory)
    {
        _serviceFactory = myServiceFactory;
    }

    public void MethodThatDoesSomething()
    {
        var service = _serviceFactory.Create();
        try
        {
            var data = service.GetSomeData();
            // do whatever
        }
        finally
        {
            _serviceFactory.Release(service);
        }
    }
}
```

To use Windsor you would add the [Windsor WCF Facility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility/) nuget package, which is Windsor plus some additional classes for handling WCF services.

Your container registration might look like this:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>()
    .AsWcfClient(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("MyServiceEndpointName")));
container.Register(Component.For<IMyServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
```

This does the following:

- Adds the "facility" or capability for the container to provide an abstract factory (I'll come back to that.)
- Adds the WCF facility for managing WCF services
- Tells the container that the implementation of `IMyService` is a WCF client using the endpoint specified in app.config/web.config named "MyServiceEndpointName".
- Tells the container that the implementation of `IMyServiceFactory` is a factory that Windsor creates. [Here's that documentation again.](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md). What that means is that you don't actually create a class to implement `IMyServiceFactory`. The container does it. When you call `Create` the factory creates the client. When you call `Release` it disposes the client.

If you wanted to you could write your own factory implementation, like this:

```
public class WcfClientMyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory
{
    public IMyService Create()
    {
        return new MyServiceClient();
    }

    public void Release(IMyService created)
    {
        var client = (MyServiceClient) created;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

(Don't quote me on the details of how to properly close a WCF client. It's been a while and I'm rusty.)
But having gotten used to using Windsor it's just a lot easier.

Having done it this way, what if you want to unit test your class assuming that `IMyService` will return specific data? Now it's really easy to use [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) or just write test double classes like this:

```
public class MyServiceDouble : IMyService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetSomeData()
    {
        return new [] {"x", "y", "z"};
    }
}

public class MyServiceFactoryDouble : IMyServiceFactory
{
    public IMyService Create()
    {
        return new MyServiceDouble();
    }

    public void Release(IMyService created)
    {
        // Nothing to clean up.
    }
}
```

Because your class doesn't know anything about `IMyService` - it doesn't know that the "normal" implementation is a WCF client - it's easy to replace it with something else.

Comment: In the implementation of IMyServiceFactory I would use the DI and then what would be the implementation of the Release() method? Wouldn't it be just proxy.Close()?
How does this differ from doing: var proxy = new ServceClient(); proxy.GetAll(); proxy.Close();
or from the using(var proxy = new ServceClient()){ (...) }?

Comment: Do I have to take care of disposing of my proxy after using even when it is instantiated in the method call and then Close() it or just Disposing() is enough?

Comment: The `Release` method helps to "hide" the implementation of the interface. It might close the WCF client, but the class using it doesn't know that. It just performs any necessary cleanup, which might be disposing, might be closing a WCF client, or might be nothing at all if it's a mocked service. The important thing is that the class doesn't know the implementation of the interface - whether it's a WCF client or something else. That way you can replace it later and also you can use a substitute (mock, test double) when unit testing your class.

Comment: I looked around and couldn't find an adequate example of this. So the high-level description I'm giving lacks the specifics to make it more useful. What DI container are you using? I may be able to provide a more concrete example.

Comment: Thank you, for your input and time :) I think it's clear now for me. I have not decided on which DI to use. I wanted to understand the principle. I was probably going to use Autofac but Windsor seems like a great idea now.

Comment: I use Windsor because it's what I was first introduced to. But it's interesting to me that the 2nd edition of Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seeman has notes on Autofac and a few others but not Windsor. Maybe I'm reading something into nothing. Every once in a while I'll play around with Autofac or one of the others just to make sure I can do the same stuff. Simple Injector goes so far as to omit features that look like they might lead to too much reliance on the container.