# Need complete DI sample for WCF

Tags: dependency-injection, wcf, unity-container, structuremap

Does anyone have a complete and working DI sample for WCF?

[Every](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/b428fb65-08b4-45c8-97cd-47ee1a1eaf41/composing-wcf-applications.aspx) [sample](http://www.jamescbender.com/bendersblog/archive/2008/04/09/extending-wcf-using-the-iinstanceprovider-and-iservicebehavior-interfaces.aspx) [I](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/07/29/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf.aspx) [find](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/12/13/wcf-dependency-injection-behavior.aspx) just gets me more confused.  Does anyone know of a complete and working standalone simple sample that works with the built in stuff?

Maybe once I get a handle of the built in stuff, I can move on to different DI frameworks such as StructureMap or Unity with WCF.

My MVC project is currently using Unity for all its DI.

Comment: See article [hosting-mock-as-wcf-service](http://bronumski.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/hosting-mock-as-wcf-service.html) and answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306934/52277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code download for my book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236) contains a full, working example.

However, most of what you'll need to know is explained in this answer: [Injecting data to a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042609/injecting-data-to-a-wcf-service/2042858#2042858)

Comment: I saw another post from your book elsewhere and it was helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx). I have already used it and it is fully working.

Comment: Thanks this one clarified a few things about using Unity

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://geekswithblogs.net/13DaysaWeek/archive/2010/12/01/dependency-injection-and-wcf-services.aspx)  is the most straightforward one I've found.

Comment: What is the proper way to set up the Unity container as mentioned in the Todo?  What should I do after `new UnityContainer();`?

Answer (score 0):

DI with **Castle Windsor**

- Official Site http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Integration-Facility.ashx
- Blog article http://ayende.com/blog/2548/wcf-windsor-integration
- Blog article with sample http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/11/windsor-wcf-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a fully working downloadable sample [here on Codeplex](https://unitywcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/101494).  It uses the Unity.WCF NuGet package, so it's really the kind of slam dunk example you are looking for.