# WCF with DI/IoC: Looking for a pattern

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, dependency-injection, unity-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Injecting data to a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042609/injecting-data-to-a-wcf-service)

I have a WCF service that looks like this: (Service-contract attributes omitted for clarity)

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void LoadBulkData(LoadRequest request);
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    IUnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();
    IDataProvider provider;

    public MyService()
    {
        unity.LoadConfiguration();
        provider = unity.Resolve<IDataProvider>();
    }

    public void LoadBulkData(LoadRequest request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As per company policy, **Microsoft Unity** must be used for DI/IoC. Because this is WCF, I can't use
constructor injection because the service implementation must use the default, parameterless constructor.

In particular, I don't like using Unity to resolve the dependency in the constructor. Does anyone
know of a way around this? Also, is there a pattern out there that might better suit my needs
here?

Comment: You can build your own SericeHostFactory that does the DI/IoC for you.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have, we use something similiar in various services and it works well.

Comment: @ChrisBint - What's wrong is that since there's no property or constructor injection, there's no opportunity to inject mocks for testing.

Comment: Excellent point considering I am testing each part of this in isolation.

Comment: I'd just like to note that your company policy is idiotic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Property Injection:

[Annotating Objects for Property (Setter) Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx)

Comment: This is probably what I'll go with for the time being. Thank you

Comment: One question after reading that article: Where would the "run-time" code be? The constructor of the service?

Comment: @ErOx - I would take a look at this article about WCF Extensibility and figure out the best place to place it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx

Comment: Property Injection implies something completely different about the class' invariants than Constructor Injection, so I don't find this a good solution - particular when (contrary to what the OP thinks) it's perfectly possible to support Constructor Injection in WCF.

Comment: @Mark -I meant that vanilla WCF doesn't support constructors w/parameters out-of-the-box. For these types of constructors, chris.house.00's answer or one of the many others available online would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug for my own blog :)

http://thirteendaysaweek.com/2010/12/01/dependency-injection-and-wcf-services/

It's eactually pretty easy to do constructor injection with WCF and Unity.  You'll end up needing a custom ServiceHost, ServiceHostFactory, an IInstanceProvider implementation that interacts with your container and an IServiceBehavior implementation.  All in all, it's not a lot of code and fairly easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, your blog post is really nice, thank you for that. Probably not what I'll go with this time around, time constraints and all, but I plan on coming back to this in the future. Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ninject and the WCF Ninject Extension.
http://ninject.org/

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Ninject as per company policy. I've used Ninject.Extensions.Wcf elsewhere, and it works brilliantly. In a more perfect world maybe...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://rafatolotti.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/wcf-unity-app-block/) blogpost describes how you can implement a custom WCF [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx)